# Dedicated server unstable, need help

Tags: server, ssd, magento

I am running a dedicated server with the following configuration:
Intel® Core™ i7-6700 Quad-Core, RAM 64 GB DDR4, SSD 500 GB SATA SSD.

I have an Uptime Robot setup and I am noticing server going offline. Yesterday morning it went offline for about an hour. I am running a Magento store on this server and a couple of Wordpress CMSs.

Can you please give me some input and advice what to do to make my server more stable and not going offline anymore?

Comment: You need to give more details. Is the machine shutting down? Or is it just losing its network connection? Or is the service shutting down?

Comment: What does /var/log/syslog* indicate around the time(s) of the outage? Run `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get your BIOS version, then go to the manufacturor's web site and see if there's an update. We'll probably do a memtest after we get more details from you about syslog and/or the outage detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turned out that a Magento extension that was running on the server was causing high CPU. It took me weeks to figure this out. In the meantime I tried several options, similar to what heynnema suggested.

Thanks for your help though!